# System.NullReferenceException thrown by AseDataReader

Tags: c#, sap-ase

I’m using Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient to access Sybase ASE data from a Console C# Application.  Not always, but from time to time I get System.NullReferenceException With following code.

It works well with only one application started, but fails with this exception if I start 10 processes at the same time in my machine.

```
public void Dummy()
{
    List<string> valueList = new List<string>();

    AseParameter[] arParms = new AseParameter[1];
    arParms[0] = new AseParameter("@date", AseDbType.Date);
    arParms[0].Value = Convert.ToDateTime("1/08/2010");

    AseCommand spCommand = new AseCommand();
    spCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    spCommand.Connection = connection;
    spCommand.CommandText = "MyStoredProcedure";

    spCommand.Parameters.AddRange(arParms);

    AseDataReader reader = spCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader["MyColumn"] != DBNull.Value)
            valueList.Add(reader["MyColumn"].ToString());
    }
}
```

It happens in the line of “while (reader.Read())”, and has following call stack.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
     at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseDataReader.Read()
     at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseDataReader.Read()
     at Dummy()

Will be very appreciated if anybody can help me out.

Comment: It happens in the line of 
“while (reader.Read())”, and has following call stack. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseDataReader.Read() 
at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseDataReader.Read() 
at Dummy()

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `spCommand.ExecuteReader()` instead of returning empty reader returns `null` object. In this case I suggest to chceck if it's null before reading:

```
AseDataReader reader = spCommand.ExecuteReader();
if(reader != null)
   while (reader.Read())
   {
        if (reader["MyColumn"] != DBNull.Value)
            valueList.Add(reader["MyColumn"].ToString());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this of course because spCommand.ExecuteReader returns a null. But unfortunately i couldn't find out why the Null Exception is thrown in the SysBook Online reference. Perhaps try with a different command behavior

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sdk_12.5.1.adonet/html/adonet/Asacommand_apiref.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx

Something like

```
reader.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
```

Or i think ŁukaszW.pl's answer will suffice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answers.

But `reader` returned from `spCommand.ExecuteReader()` is not `null`. The exception happens inside `Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseDataReader.Read()` as you can see from the call stack.

Following is the code I got from reflector.

```
public bool Read()
{
  this.OnTraceEnterEvent("Read", null);
  if (this._disposed)
  {
    throw new NullReferenceException();
  }
  if (this.IsClosed)
  {
    throw new AseException(DriverMsgNumber.ERR_RESULTSET_DEAD, null);
  }
  bool state = false;
  if (!this._bNoResultSet)
  {
    state = this.Peform_Next();
    state = this.CheckSingleRow(state);
  }
  this.OnTraceExitEvent("Read", state);
  return state;
}
```

I can see one `NullReferenceException` could be thrown with `_disposed` as `true`. But not quite sure if it's the exception getting thrown in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I would try scoping the objects with Using:

```
using (AseCommand spCommand = new AseCommand())
{
     //etc..

     using (AseDataReader reader = spCommand.ExecuteReader())
     {
         // until end of while loop
     }
}
```

We have always needed to scope our sybase objects, connection objects in particular, due to strange behaviors. In any case I don't think the sybase libs are managed, so it is really best practices to clean up explicitly wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since I stumbled upon this problem and found the reason, here is it :
My reader wasn't null,  but it had "IsClosed = true" because the connection was closed before reading the data.

According to http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sdk_12.5.1.adonet/html/adonet/Isclosed_asadatareader_apiref.htm once the reader is closed, you can only call IsClosed and RecordsAffected.